# How to use the viewParams option of a GeoServer layer defined as a SQL View in a Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geoserver, wms

I set up a PostGIS database that I added in GeoServer via a parameterized SQL view. The parameter I set is 'year' : it permits to select only the polygons of my database that have this year as a property.

I know this worked because I can successfully use the layer preview of GeoServer on my layer with the local link : http://localhost:9999/geoserver/cite/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&viewParams=year:0&layers=cite%3Achoix_annee&bbox=-56.6015625%2C25.16517336866393%2C-16.875%2C47.040182144806664&width=768&height=422&srs=EPSG%3A404000&styles=&format=application/openlayers

The interesting option there is 'viewParams=year:0'.

In Leaflet, I used the following code to import my layer via wms:

```
<script>
// Find our map id
var map = L.map('map');

var wmsLayer =  L.tileLayer.wms('/geoserver/gwc/service/wms', {
    layers: 'cartowiki:choix',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    viewparams: 'year:1000'
}).addTo(map);

// Set the map view
map.setView([46.988332, 2.605527], 2);

</script>
```

It works the first time but then GeoWebCache intervenes and prevents me from getting results fitted to the year I'm asking, it always gives me the results for the first year I asked. I tried to specify the year parameter with a regular expression in the tile caching module of my layer but it doesn't work and I cannot figure out why.

This is a view of my settings in geoserver: [geoserver settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz7dP.png)

Thanks,

Comment: What kind of URL is being requested through Leaflet? (Remember, the [browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) are your friends)

Comment: I checked and it looks like that : http://localhost:9999/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=cartowiki%3Achoix&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&viewparams=year%3A1000&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=10018754.171394622,-10018754.171394622,20037508.342789244,0. The viewparams is there as it should be but it seems to have no effect

Answer (score 0):

you have to dynamically set viewparams value then refresh wms layer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).